# Handling i18n in javascript files

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, internationalization, primefaces

For example, my app relies heavily on the use of AJAX when doing CRUD operation.

As of now, messages are hardcoded similar to this.

```
function handleSaveNewMember(xhr, status, args) {  
    if(args.validationFailed || !args.result) {   
    }else{  
        showmsg.show([{summary:'Add New Member', detail: 'Successfully Added New Member', severity: 'info'}]);
    }  
}
```

But what if you deploy your app to a different locale?  Then how do you handle the i18n feature?

I used Primefaces here by the way.

Comment: Why don't you just set a `FacesMessage`?

Comment: Hi my app is highly ajaxified and relies on javascript.  In this case aside from showing messages, I need to turnoff the dialog and other stuff.

Comment: I don't see why that would form a problem.

Comment: Ahh yeah.. After some more reading on your post I think I know what your pointing at.  Thanks BalusC. You're the man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be the best solution, but in the past I've essentially linked a js file that contains string constants that I reference in code. On load, I load the appropriate js file for the current culture. Make sure to have some kind of defaults for each constant should that file not load though.

Comment: Effectively thats the/an accepted way to do things  http://24ways.org/2007/javascript-internationalisation

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use JQuery - we are using this nice little plugin in our project for i18n -

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

Fits our needs well..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to iterate over you properties file and populate it into a `HashMap` say `mapOfLabels` then turn into a Json string with Gson `gson.toJson(mapOfLabels);`

than place the Json string into a bean variable that will be "linked" via getter to your `xhtml` page like this

```
<h:inputText id="locLabelsID" value="#{myBean.locLabelsField}" styleClass="hide"/>
```

and in js side you can simply access it and parse it with jQuery like this :

```
var myJsonVar= $("#locLabelsID").val();
locLabels = $.parseJSON(myJsonVar);
```

and access it with your label key like this

```
locLabels[key];
```

of course the init of the hash map is being done only once and same goes for the init in the js side...